# Outlook Rules - Sent Only to "Me"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

How do I create an Outlook rule for emails sent only to "me," where "me" is my alternate email address?

I know that you can create rules sent only to "me," where "me" is the email owning the mailbox, but how do I apply that to emails autoforwarded from my other email?

I was thinking of somehow creating a rule where the total recipients is 1, and the recipient is the other address, but how would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean about "alternate email address"? An alias of your account?

Comment: No. An email that has auto-forwarding turned on. My organization has legacy and new accounts, and I am auto-forwarding emails from the legacy inbox to my new one.

Answer (score 0):

> but how do I apply that to emails autoforwarded from my other email?

As i know, rules with condition (sent only to "me", where "me" is my alternate email) cannot be applied to the autoforwarded emails. Because the To field actually is changed.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.